# MySQL joining tables and returning the latest row from the second table when the comparison is made between identical values

Tags: php, mysql

I have table 1: users

```
id | name |

1  | john |
2  | garry|
3  | sam  |
```

And table two called posts:

```
id | user_id |     title    |   posted

1  |    1    | Something    | 1551128761
2  |    1    | Else         | 1551128761
3  |    3    | Some Title   | 1551122745
4  |    2    | Demo Title   | 1551129777
5  |    3    | Something    | 1551126793
```

user_id in the second table is the id of the user in the first table

I need to get the latest post out of the table and i'm doing that currently by using this query:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, p.title 
FROM users AS u 
LEFT JOIN posts AS p 
ON p.user_id= u.id 
WHERE p.posted = ( SELECT MAX(posted) FROM posts WHERE user_id = u.id )
ORDER BY u.id 
LIMIT 15
```

But the problem with this query is that if the timestamp is the same for the same user (in this example for user with user_id `1` the timestamp is the same) i'm getting both of those rows instead of just the latest one(the latest one has the highest id)

Comment: Shouldn't `ON p.ticker_id = u.id` be `ON p.user_id = u.id`?

Comment: @Utkanos edit mistake, thanks

Comment: I'm having the data in front of me and i'm getting both those rows, but if i add one second to either one of those two rows i'm getting only one(which is exactly what i need

Comment: Try `DISTINCT` in your selection part, before `u.id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this MySQL query:

```
SELECT u.id, 
       u.name, 
       p.title 
FROM   users AS u 
       JOIN posts AS p 
         ON p.id = (SELECT pi.id 
                    FROM   posts AS pi 
                    WHERE  pi.user_id = u.id 
                    ORDER  BY pi.id DESC 
                    LIMIT  1);
```

Tested and works fine. Here is a demo: [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=72cb002da02891b6ab2185f05f83f0bc)

### To speed up `select` query, consider adding `indexes`

```
ALTER TABLE posts ADD INDEX(user_id);
ALTER TABLE posts ADD INDEX(posted);
```

Comment: 8000 as for now - it takes around 2 seconds with my old one and around 25 seconds with this one, but yours actually does what i need

Comment: Suggestion: useful index is on posts (user_id, posted, id).. try indexing and check the speed again

Comment: how should i do that?

Comment: If you are using PHPMyAdmin to view your table structure, you should be able to see different tabs on clicking a table name.. Click `Structure > Index` in every row to add indexes else run SQL queries for all three columns like this:
`ALTER TABLE posts ADD INDEX(user_id);`

Comment: Ok, i've done it as you said, it is moving faster than ever, thanks!

Comment: Quick question tho, isn't `id` already indexed ? (it is the primary key and auto incremented)

Comment: Yes, no need to add index on primary keys - they are already indexed :)

Comment: is an index going to work if the column data is not unique?

Answer (score 1):

One option using id column from posts table as following. This is assuming id is going to be different for each post record is posts table. [Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cf4502ab6eae6f4c4acd22faea176cee)

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, p.title,p.posted
FROM users AS u 
LEFT JOIN posts AS p 
ON p.user_id= u.id 
WHERE (p.posted,p.id) = ( SELECT MAX(posted),MAX(id) FROM posts WHERE user_id = u.id )
ORDER BY u.id
```

Comment: hi @vmaroli, it works but it takes the query time from 2 seconds to ~25seconds :(

Comment: Is id column the primary key or having a unique index in posts table ? If your id for posts is unique and guaranteed to  in increasing order, then you could filter by id instead of timestamp. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0fce43f5fbc0961336c31c7027e853a6 This should give a much better performance as it is an access by unique index/primary key

Comment: `id` column is unique auto_increment for both tables. in the table post i'm identifying posts/user by `user_id` which can be more than one(not unique) - for each post posted by that user

Comment: Then the SQL mentioned in my previous comment should work right? Since its access using primary key should be fast also.

Comment: Yes, it does and i'm using it. I just used the above one first until i've got to this one so i already "preferred" that one. But again, i'm using this one

Answer (score 0):

How about restructuring the query slightly?

```
SELECT posts.title, users.id, users.name
FROM posts, users 
WHERE posts.user_id = users.id 
ORDER BY posts.posted DESC, posts.id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Essentially selecting from posts, ordering by the `posted` timestamp and secondly the `id` of the post in descending order in case timestamp is the same.